# Loop through array, checking each element with networking call/callback function, and then go to default if desired element is not found

Tags: ios, swift, networking, callback

Because of the very specific nature of this question, I could not find an answer anywhere.  Basically I want to create a messaging conversation with a specific user, but only if a conversation with that user doesn't already exist.  I am looping through an array of conversations, and for each conversation I fetch the identity of the other user via a call to my backend.  However, if no conversation is found with a particular user, then I want to create a new conversation.  This is what I am doing:

```
for convo in convos {
    HTTPManager.getOtherUserFromConversation(conversation: convo, success: { (otherUser) in
        if desiredUser == otherUser {
            //Found the desired conversation, so bring the user 
            //to it instead of creating a new one
        }
    }, failure: {
        //Networking failure
    })     
}
//IF WE DIDN'T FIND IT, CREATE A NEW CONVERSATION HERE
```

I have thought of making a boolean value called "found" and setting it to `true` if we find the desired conversation, but I don't know how to wait until the last callback has executed before checking this boolean in order to avoid calling the check too early. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic solution for this is using dispatch-group
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

There are many code examples for this. The idea is that each network call should be in a separate task and the system lets you know when all tasks are done (this is where you check "found").

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.  One more question: lets say two conversations with that user already exist.  Would it be ok to check if `if desiredUser == otherUser && !found` at the if statement to guarantee that I don't push two conversations on the navigationController or would this create a possible concurrent modification issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about create callback function that will called when the all the request to check the convos is done, or when the correct convo is found.

```
func checkConvoIfExist(convos: [Convo]){
    var found = false
    var countCheck = 0

    for convo in convos {
        HTTPManager.getOtherUserFromConversation(conversation: convo, success: { (otherUser) in
            countCheck += 1
            if desiredUser == otherUser {
                //Found the desired conversation
                found = true
                callbackCheckConvo(result: found, convo: convo)
                break // to stop the loop
            }else{
                if (countCheck == convos.count){
                    callbackCheckConvo(result: found)
                }
            }
        }, failure: {
            //Networking failure
            countCheck += 1
            if (countCheck == convos.count){
              callbackCheckConvo(result: found)
            }
        })     
    } 
}

func callbackCheckConvo(result: Bool, convo: Convo = nil){
    if (result){
       //found the desired conversation, so bring the user to it instead of creating a new one
    }else{
       //convo not found, create new one
    }
}
```